# why python adding \ to my file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am parsing xml file using:

```
  lxml.etree.parse(xmlFile)
```

I extracted some node attributes which contain single backslash
and save them into dictionary

Then I write the dictionary into a file using:

```
f = open(myFile, 'w')
for k, v in sorted(dic.items()):
    f.write(str((k,v)))
    f.write('\n')
f.flush()
f.close()
```

Know the problem is that after parsing if I write the tree into a file using:

```
     tree.write('output4.xml')
```

the tree is exactly as the original file BUT 
the dictionary that saved into myFile has \\ instead of each \
So why python adding \ wherever it found one.

Example:
this is the original attribute:

```
"\displaystyle\mathbb{Z}_{n}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}"
```

and in the dictionary file it becomes:

```
'\\\displaystyle\\\mathbb{Z}_{n}\\\longrightarrow\\\mathbb{Z}'
```

Comment: it's only representation...

Answer (score 0):

`str((k,v))` uses the [`repr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/166749) of `k` and `v`:

```
>>> k = r'\textit{foo}'
>>> v = 'bla'
>>> s = str((k, v))
>>> s
"('\\\\textit{foo}', 'bla')"
```

This has the benefit of being deserializable with `ast.literal_eval`, because the escaped strings from `repr` have the same syntax as Python literals:

```
>>> import ast
>>> print(ast.literal_eval(s)[0])
```

If this is not what you want, you'll have to find some other way of writing out the pairs.

Comment: ok this is good in a way that it write the key correctly but it does not write the value. I tried to make it as tuple but this gives error that it only can write str